# JavaFX PrinterJob WebView

Tags: java, javafx

i'm trying to print a webView of "www.google.com" but,
the print not include the background images,it print only texts, how i include it?

The Code,

```
public void print() {
        logger.info("Print Event  -  Message:  " + "Iniciando Impressora");
        ChoiceDialog dialog = new ChoiceDialog(Printer.getDefaultPrinter(), Printer.getAllPrinters());
        dialog.setTitle("Escolha uma Impressora!");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Confirme a escolha de uma impressora!");
        Optional<Printer> opt = dialog.showAndWait();
        if (opt.isPresent()) {
            Printer p = opt.get();
            PageLayout pageLayout = p.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(p);
            webEngine.print(job);
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
```

I need to enable the background images to be printed too.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be that the page’s CSS contains rules which display background images for screen media but not for printed media.  Are those background images displayed when you load the page in a regular web browser and do Print Preview?

Comment: Yes, in browser show the image but, have a check box to enable and disable background images, i think is that option i need in printerjob. The page is "www.google.com".

Comment: Try ctrl + p in the google page, in left bottom have 'options' and a checkbox to enable and disable second plan background images. Is exactly this in PrinterJob, but is disable.